# Apache Superset - Module Federation

Tags: webpack, apache-superset, webpack-module-federation

Is it possible to connect a supernet as a microfront?

I use a standard configuration for export, but nothing comes out.

webpack.config superset

```
const plugins = [
  new ModuleFederationPlugin({
    name: 'superset',
    library: { type: 'var', name: 'superset' },
    filename: 'entryFile.js',
    exposes: {
      './App': addPreamble('/src/profile/App.tsx'),
    },
  }),
```

1. Launch docker-compose up
2. http://localhost:8088/entryFile.js returns error

```
{"errors": [{"message": "404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.", "error_type": "GENERIC_BACKEND_ERROR", "level": "error", "extra": {"issue_codes": [{"code": 1011, "message": "Issue 1011 - Superset encountered an unexpected error."}]}}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

The file is available at the address - localhost:8088/static/assets/entryFile.js